# change hight of the tableView cell does not work

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

hello guys now I have `UITableViewCell` should have dynamic height , this cell have 3 labels , I have added them in to stack and I added all requirements 
to let tableViewCell be dynamic height

1- The code used for automatic cell height

```
notifications.rowHeight = UITableView.automaticDimension

notifications.estimatedRowHeight = 150
```

2- I have set constraints leading and trailing and bottom and top space to the superView.

3- The number of lines for each label is equal zero

this is cell before run 
[enter link description here](https://ibb.co/Tg33GRX)

this cell after run  https://ibb.co/5YCMpfK

Comment: Check the constraints of tick and cross buttons

Answer (score 0):

1. Check if your stack view doesn't have `height constraint`.
2. Check if your labels do not have any `height constraint`.
3. Give your stackview top and bottom constraints a specific value and make them greater than equal to `topContraint >= 5`  `bottomconstraint >=5`.
4. Change the property of stack view to `Fill proportionally` and give `spacing` according to your needs.

Comment: Thank you very much I will try it and give you the feedback

Answer (score 0):

The `constraints` of your `tableViewCell` must be like:

[image]

**Properties of `stackView`:**

1. `Axis`: Vertical
2. `Alignment`: Fill
3. `Distribution`: Fill Proportionally
4. `Spacing`: 5 (as per your requirement)

**Number of lines** of all 3 `labels` = 0

Comment: I have changed from label to UITextView worked perfectly with you constraints  thank you very much